# knitr: include figures in report *and* output figures to separate files

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, figures

Not only would I like my figures to appear in my knitr-generated report, but I would also like to output them to separate files, too. To do this, I have included code like the following:

````
```{r}
  #Plot figure in report
  plot(x,y)

  #Plot figure in file
  pdf(file="MyFig.pdf")
  plot(x,y)
  dev.off()
```
````

This works fine, but I expect there's a more elegant solution for this already built into knitr. Is there a chunk option or something similar that achieves the same results?

Comment: Worth highlighting here another solution which saves all `ggplot` s from `.Rmd`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77563203/how-to-save-all-ggplots-of-a-rmd-as-rds

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the option `self_contained: no` if you are using [`html_document`](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html), or `keep_tex: yes` if you use [`pdf_document`](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html), so that rmarkdown will not remove the figure files after rendering the output document.

Comment: Is there a related solution for R Notebooks? Using this option with `output: html_notebook` doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

Keyword `dev='pdf'` as explained by Yihui here http://yihui.name/knitr/options/

Together with other options I have found useful:

````
```{r 'setup', echo = FALSE, cache = FALSE}
    opts_chunk$set(dev = c('pdf', 'png'), 
        fig.align = 'center', fig.height = 5, fig.width = 8.5, 
        pdf.options(encoding = "ISOLatin9.enc")) 
```
````

Comment: I use `output: html_document` most of the time, and putting `'png'` first in the list made the html render nicely and saved the figures as well. In combination with `fig.path`, `fig.width`, and `fig.height`, I was able to come up with a decent solution.:

    `{r plot_stuff, fig.width=10, fig.height=5, fig.path='figures/', dev=c('png', 'pdf')}`

Comment: This is really nice, keeping the hmtl document self-contained, while saving the figures from that same report as separate figures, too. @Yihui's answer above seems to me to also yield separate figures, but an html file that depends on that folder for its figures, which is often a pain when sharing reports.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to save the figures as files:
https://www.njtierney.com/post/2018/02/28/three-r-tips/

"Tip number 1: Save the images that you create"