# R Notebook: Include figures in report and save plots

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

I'm using an R Notebook and I'd like my plots to automatically save to disk when the code is run, as well as display inline.

[knitr: include figures in report *and* output figures to separate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992239/knitr-include-figures-in-report-and-output-figures-to-separate-files) addresses this for R Markdown but the solution given doesn't work for an R Notebook. Is there a similar option for R Notebooks?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the knitr fig.path option:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "path/to/figures/")
```

Where `path/to/figures/` is the path to a subdirectory where your figures will be saved.  The trailing slash is necessary.   This should be a relative path, either relative to  the RNotebook file or to the project directory.  See `here::here()` for a handy way to locate the project directory.

This will put each figure into that directory; figure names will be based on the chunk name (so name your chunks!)

Comment: This didn't work for me. The plot displays in the saved notebook HTML file but there is no plot saved into the specified folder.

Comment: I also tried setting it directly within the chunk but that didn't work either: ````{r test, fig.path="/figs/"}
hist(iris$Sepal.Length)
````

Comment: Try `{r test, fig.path="figs/"}`.  Currently you're creating a top-level directory under /.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, however, that doesn't work either. Nothing is saved to the `"figs/"` sub-directory.

Comment: How could you specify the figure driver to use? Such a jpeg or pdf?

Comment: You specify that using the `dev` chunk option: `opts_chunk$set(dev = 'png')`.  You can also specify multiple devices, for example: `opts_chunk$set(dev = c('pdf', 'png')` will generate PDF and PNG versions of each plot.

Answer (score 0):

This is what eventually worked for me (see @TCZhang 's answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598873/r-notebook-markdown-does-not-save-chunk-plots-using-fig-path-chunk-option)):

In addition to setting the knitr chunk `fig.path="figures/"` option suggested by @DonJ, try setting `output: html_document`, or just press the dropdown next to the `Preview [Notebook]` button at the top and press `Knit to HTML`. I think the reason this isn't working is that your output is set to `output: html_notebook`.

I don't know why this doesn't work specifically when the doc is in R Notebook format. I would also prefer if this worked for `output: html_notebook`, so it might be an issue we need to open with RStudio or knitr.