# Write pdf to figure folder, but delete pngs

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

This is a follow-up question about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27996644/11374827). I have set the knitr chunk options to output a png and pdf version of plots in a folder, as well as use the pngs in the knitted report.

However, I'd only like to keep the pdf version of the figure and discard the png file. Is there a knitr-equivalent of `on.exit()` to clean up the pngs after knitting? Or an option I overlooked?

With the rmarkdown document below, how do I automatically clean up the png version of the plot after knitting? (Or not produce it as a standalone file in the first place)

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: "21/10/2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  echo = TRUE,
  dev = c("png", "pdf"),
  fig.path = here::here(
    "figures",
    gsub("\\.Rmd$", "\\\\", basename(knitr::current_input()))
  )
)
```

```{r my_plot}
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point()
```
````

Comment: I might misunderstand the question, but if you don't want to create png files, why do you set `dev = c("png","pdf")`?

Comment: I want the output document to contain png images, but not pdf images. I want the pdf files as a side-effect of knitting the document for a collaborator who likes them to be available. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

That is not exactly what you are looking for, but manually removing `eval=FALSE` from the following chunk, deletes the wanted files:

````
```{r eval=FALSE, include=FALSE}
fList <-  dir("figures")
fList <- fList[stringr::str_detect(fList,"\\.png$")]
file.remove(paste0("figures/",fList))
```
````